# What is regex for square bracket character in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

Can anyone tell me how to make regex for square brackets ( [ ] ) in JavaScript?

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape the square brackets with a backslash: `\[\]`

Comment: Thank you bro, I was searching this for half of an hour